# Symfony access entity variable from Controller

Tags: symfony, variables, entity

I somehow can't get this to work. I had it working, messed up my php server & had no backups from the working version... I guess I had a similar solution.

```
public function schreibenAction() {
  $user = $this->getDoctrine()
          ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
          ->find(1); //How can I search for the currently logged user?

  if (!$user) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException(
              'No user found for id 1'
      );
  }

  $path = $user->getPath();
  return $this->render('default/unterlagen/schreiben.html.twig', array(
              'path' => $path,
    ));
}
```

I need the path value from the database..

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.password AS password_3, t0.path AS path_4, t0.is_active AS is_active_5 FROM app_users t0 WHERE t0.id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get currently logged user with $this->getUser() in your controller. Look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object).